# AKS not writing logs to Application Insights

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

I have .Net Core 3.1 web api which is deployed to AKS. I have created Azure App Insights instance to write the logs.
I followed
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcore6
to configure the .Net application.

Added Microsoft.ApplicationInsights Nuget package

Added connection string in appsettings

Added services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(); in startup.cs

Running api from local pc I can see telemetry being logged in Visual Studio output.

But when I deployed to Azure nothing is flowing into App Insights. Absolutely nothing.

I am new to this and checked pod logs but dint find anything in it. The connection string is correct.

From my local pc I tried to write to Actual App Insights. But although I can see telemetry in Visual Studio nothing is going to Azure.
I am assuming because "Accept data ingestion from public networks not connected through a Private Link Scope" is false for the App Insight instance.So this is also not helping me to debug.I cannot change this setting.

The Azure account is linked to On Premise network.

Can someone point to me what could be the issue

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore was not working when using Connection String. When I changed to InstrumentKey the logs started flowing. Weird as MSFT recommendation is to use connection string